# I wish to have a structure, wherein I have an UBUNTU Server machine, and my Agents connect to the same using Thin clients. How can I do that

Tags: server, file-server

Well I use a structure in my organisation which is as below.

I have a Windows Server
20 Agents connect to that server through a Thin Client using RDP and Terminal Services.

Now I want to replace the Windows Server with an Ubuntu Server.

Is it possible to do that?

if yes then How?

I would not like the agents to feel the difference, as majorly they use only browser based applications. and storage of files. For Office, I use Open Office.

Comment: Maybe a bit outdated, but still: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP